# PHP OOP and Extends in a game logic

Tags: php, oop, extends

I would be very grateful to have a very simplified example of using PHP, OOP and Extends.

An example for the creation of a character class, two specific types Mage and Warrior and a fight system.

Something like:

```
class Character{

}
class Wizard extends Character{

}
class Warrior extends  Character{

}
class Battle {

}
```

Just to understand the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a point of start, and a poor example for your case.

Every character has a name.
So, the name of character can be in Character class.

```
class Character {
    public $name = "unknown";
}
```

Every Person has also a standard force and a life

```
class Character {
    public $name = "unknown";
    public $force = 10;
    public $life = 100;
}
```

The extended class inherits these properties. For example:

```
$me = new Wizard();
echo "The name of wizard is " . $me->name; // The name of wizard is unknown
```

We can set the name of character in costructor method

```
class Character {
    public $name = "unknown";
    public $force = 10;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}


$me = new Wizard("Gandalf");
echo "The name of wizard is " . $me->name; // The name of wizard is Gandalf
```

A Wizard have something that a simple Character don't have. Mana for example:

```
class Wizard extends Character{
    public $mana = 100;
}
```

And

```
$me = new Wizard("Gandalf");
echo "The name of wizard is " . $me->name; // The name of wizard is Gandalf
echo "\nAnd its mana is " . $me->mana;
```

A warrior have a multiplier of standard force, because he has a weapon.

```
class Warrior extends  Character{
    public $weapon = 12;
}

$opponent = new Warrior("Grunt");
echo "The name of warrior is " . $opponent->name . " and the powrfull of its weapon is " . $opponent->weapon;
```

Every character have a powerfull depends on its force:

```
class Character {
    public $name = "unknown";
    public $force = 10;
    public $life = 100;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    protected function get_powerfull() {
        return $this->force;
    }
}
```

but for wizard the force depend on mana

```
class Wizard extends Character{
    public $mana = 100;
    // override
    public function get_powerfull() { 
        return $this->mana;
    }
}
```

and for warriors depend on weapon and its force.

```
class Warrior extends  Character{
    public $weapon = 12;
    // override
    public function get_powerfull() {
        return $this->weapon*$this->force;
    }
}
```

Every Character can fight and the result depend of powerfull that depend on class

```
class Battle {
    public function fight(Character $player1, Character $player2) {
        $damage1 = $player1->get_powerfull();
        $damage2 = $player2->get_powerfull();
        $player1->life -= $damage2;
        $player2->life -= $damage1;

        echo "{$player1->name} hits {$player2->name} for $damage1 points.<br/>";
        echo "{$player2->name} hits {$player1->name} for $damage2 points.<br/>";
    }
}
```

and

```
$me = new Wizard("Gandalf");
echo "The name of wizard is " . $me->name . "<br/>"; // The name of wizard is Gandalf

echo "\nAnd its mana is " . $me->mana. "<br/>";

$opponent = new Warrior("Grunt");
echo "The name of warrior is " . $opponent->name . " and the powrfull of its weapon is " . $opponent->weapon. "<br/>";
```

So:

```
$battle = new Battle();
$battle->fight($me,$opponent);
```

output:

```
Gandalf hits Grunt for 100 points.
Grunt hits Gandalf for 120 points.
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks for your patience for a newbie like me. ^ _ ^

Comment: +1, although I think mine is simpler, it's not nearly as functional :)

Answer (score 3):

This example that you posted, simplified:

```
class Character{

}

class Mage extends Character{

}

class Warrior extends Character{

}

class Battle {

}
```

I've removed the empty comments, the extra space after `Warrior extends` and corrected the spelling of `Mage`.

Comment: HAHAHAHA +1 for the humor from me too

Comment: I have corrected the typos. But I needed an example on how to use OOP and Classes in a fantasy game.